# Remove shell access in a TomCat Image

Tags: image, shell, tomcat, alpine-linux

I have build a custom TomCat image based on alpine:3.18.3.
Now, the issue I am having is that I cannot remove the shell access.
I have tried this:

```
RUN chsh -s /sbin/nologin root
```

and

```
RUN usermod -s /sbin/nologin root
```

The image build completes fine, but when I start the container I still have shell access.
What am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance,
Mike

Comment: Do you log as root on the container?

Comment: yes. I run the container as root